# Kafka Materialized Views TTL

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, materialized-views

As far as I know, Kafka by default will keep the records in the topics for 7 days and then delete them. But how about the Kafka Materialized Views, how long Kafka will keep the data there(infinitive or limited time)? Also, does Kafka replicates Materialized Views over the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka topics can either be configured with retention time or with log compaction. For log compaction, the latest record for each key will never be deleted, while older record with the same key are garbage collected in regular intervals. See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction

When Kafka Streams creates a `KTable` or state store and creates a changelog topic for fault-tolerance, it will create this changelog topic with log compactions enabled.

> Note: if you read a topic directly as a `KTable` or `GlobalKTable` (ie, `builder.table(...)`), no additional changelog topic will be created but the source topic will be used for this purpose. Thus, the source topic should be configured with log compaction (and not with retention time).

You can configure the desired replication factor with `StreamConfig` parameter `repliaction.factor`. You can also manually change the replication factor at any time if you wish, eg, via `bin/kafka-topics.sh` command.

Comment: FYI: You actually can configure a topic with both log-compaction *and* retention time (in case a reader is wondering).